# Cannot create new file in Android app - Works on eclipse (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, file

I have Java code that creates a wav file from a buffer of double values and header information.

In eclipse it works fine and the wav file is created each run.

However I have transfered the code to android studio and the file does not get created (Every other part of the code seems to work fine ).

Please see below the section of code below

```
public static void createEventWav(ArrayList<Double> event, String
  fileName, Context context) {


    try {

         int sampleRate = 44100; // Samples per second
        double duration = event.size() / sampleRate; // Seconds

        // Calculate the number of frames required for specified duration
        long numFrames = (long) (event.size());

        System.out.println("Number frames " + numFrames);
        System.out.println("Duration " + duration);

        // Create a wav file with the name specified as the first argument
         WavFile wavFileEvent = WavFile.newWavFile(new File(fileName + ".wav"), 1, numFrames, 16, sampleRate);



        // Create a buffer
        double[] bufferEvent = new double[(int) numFrames];

        for (int loop = 0; loop < event.size(); loop++) {
            bufferEvent[loop] = event.get(loop);
        }

        int numberFrames = (int) numFrames;

        wavFileEvent.writeFrames(bufferEvent, numberFrames);
```

This chunk of code creates an object from another class "WavFile.java" The constuctor it uses can be seen below:

```
  public static WavFile newWavFile(File file, int numChannels,long numFrames, int validBits, long sampleRate) throws IOException, WavFileException
{
```

After Running on Android studio The file does not seem to exist. 
Perhaps this is the wrong way to go about creating and storing a new file on Android Studio.

Any advice on how to rectify this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `fileName`? `new File(fileName + ".wav")` is not normally how you create `File` objects in Android (regardless of IDE), because in Android we have limited places where we can read and write files. That gets even *more* limited with Android Q/R.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: @CommonsWareThis is a String that is passed into the method to name the file being created. It is dynamically created based on how many wav files that need to be created. It can be seen at the top of the code. Can you please share with me the proper way to create a File object